# Переустановка MacBook

Tags: macos

Принесли MacBook, жесткий диск форматирован под чистую. В recovery mode не входит. Как и чем можно восстановить Mac OS? Где взять образ? Чем записать? Говорят UltraIso умеет, но не могу найти образ Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут есть образа MacOS](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=1368)

Записать можно программой Trans Mac.

В конце [статьи1](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook) и [статьи2](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air) таблица по которой можно узнать какие версии подходят для Вашего бука.